# Find number of elements in a class with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a good gem to find the number of elements with a certain class? For example,

```
<div class="fun">
<p class="fun">
</p>
</div
```

And then find that there are two elements with the fun class. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need a gem for that, you can do it with jquery

Comment: Based on the result, that finding out the number of class, what are you going to do, need some context on the question

Comment: @RameshKumarThiyagarajan jQuery is not the solution to all problems in the world. There are a variety of server-side problems that can't be solved with jQuery.

Comment: I agree, still i dont get the full context of the question, so i cannot able to say which is the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) is a Ruby XML/HTML parser.

You can [parse the string](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) and then use XPath or CSS selectors to execute queries, including fetching (and counting) the number of items matching a specific class.